# More than one file in module

Tags: module, rust

I work on an implementation of the Repository pattern in Rust.

I need to have two (or more) files:

- `entity.rs` — data descriptions
- `repository.rs` — data access methods
- ...

Problem:

One file implies one mod. This means that for a function in `repository.rs` to have access to struct field from `entity.rs` it is required that `field` be `pub`. Is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: Why is making the field `pub` a problem for you? (additional reading: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#visibility-and-privacy)

Comment: Some fields must be not accessible directly, like a getter or setter as example

Comment: So, if I understand, the field should be `pub` internally (within 2/3 modules) but private to external clients of the crate (or possibly other modules in the crate)?

Comment: Approximately. The main problem is to divide the logic into multiple files.
I need to have descendants an another file (module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rust, modules are self-contained. Unlike C++ or Java there is no cheating via either `friend` or the use of reflection.

As such, if you (arbitrarily) attempt to separate the definition of the `struct` from the methods in charge of maintaining its encapsulation, you will fight against the language.

---

*Solution 1: Prefer non-member non-friend functions*

Define the methods absolutely requiring access to the fields in `entity.rs`; if you follow the "Prefer non-member non-friend functions" guideline from C++, you should see that actually most methods do NOT need to access the fields directly. For example, `empty` can be defined in terms of `len`:

```
fn empty(c: &Container) -> bool { c.len() == 0 }
```

Then, `repository.rs` can add many other methods if it needs to, but has to go through the "minimal" interface exported by `entity.rs` to achieve its needs. Since you are in control of both modules, you can tweak the methods of `entity.rs` at will anyway so it should not be an issue.

I would point out that encapsulation-wise, this is *the* sensible decision: reducing the number of methods that may access the internals of an object reduces the number of methods that may put this object in an invalid state.

This solution is advantageous because you are not fighting the language.

---

*Solution 2: Total split*

Another solution is to duplicate your entities:

- have the internal entity, entirely public
- have the external entity, opaque

This is achieved by:

```
pub struct SomeEntImpl {
    pub field0: i32,
}

pub struct SomeEnt {
    inner: SomeEntImpl,
}
```

The authorized modules will be given references to a `SomeEntImpl`, while others will have to use the restricted interface available through `SomeEnt`. The control over who sees what will be achieved by careful exports.

This solution will probably drive you insane.

Comment: Second solution is more flexible, think that what need for me. Thanks! =)